# Android - Start Intent Based on Carousel Selection (onItemSelected)

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm attempting to modify a bit of code which displays a toast when one of several items is selected in the following image carousel found here:

https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-carousel-view/source/browse/src/net/pocketmagic/android/carousel/MainActivity.java

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {}

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        m_carouselAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString()); 
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
         CarouselDataItem docu =  (CarouselDataItem) m_carouselAdapter.getItem((int) arg3);
         if (docu!=null)
             Toast.makeText(this, "You've clicked on:"+docu.getDocText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}



}
```

I'd like to modify this to start an intent depending on which item is selected

for example:

```
  if (arg== 1){
          Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Activity1.class);
          MyActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
      } else if { (arg== 2){
          Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Activity2.class);
          MyActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
      }}
```

How might this be accomplished?

Full Source:
https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-carousel-view/

Comment: And what is your question or problem exactly?

Comment: so you want to open item based on its content type ?

Comment: I want to start a different item based upon the selection in a carousel - https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-carousel-view/

Answer (score 0):

```
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // display view for selected item
    displayView(position);
}

     private void displayView(int position) {
// update the main content with called Fragment
switch (position) {


case 1:
    //home();
    Intent i = new Intent(this,Design_Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    this.finish();
    break;
case 2:
    //profile();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Profile.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
    break;
case 3:
    //credit();
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,Credits.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
    this.finish();
    break;
case 4:
    //Logout();
    Intent z = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    z.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
              Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
              Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(z);
        this.finish();
    break;

default:
    break;
}
```

Try this code hope this will be useful for you..

Comment: I'm trying to adapt that to my context... what should I use instead of position in my case? Would that be count?

https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-carousel-view/source/browse/src/net/pocketmagic/android/carousel/MainActivity.java

Comment: Can you show how this might apply in my situation? I'm trying to figure out what paramater I should use instead of switch(position) and I'm really not sure... (and the other answer to this question is WAY off - so I think you're my only hope :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you, use this code at click event.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      Uri uri =Uri.fromFile(file);
      intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimetypeOfFile);
      startActivity(intent);
```

here you get mimetype of your file , which can be retrieve

```
  MimeTypeMap mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
  mimeType.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);
```

*fileExtension* is like *.txt* for **text fil**e

if any confusion ,Plz let me know

Comment: That's not it at all... I'm trying to start a new intent based upon the item selected in the carousel found here: https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-carousel-view/ 


we are not opening any files... your references to mimetypes is pointless and useless (the other answer is much closer to what I need - I'm just trying to figure out how to adapt it to this example at this point (if youd still like to try to answer the question) 

https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-carousel-view/

Comment: this code will find suitable app present in device to open the file.

Comment: what file? I'm not trying to open a file

Comment: I think each item in carousel is a file , which onclick should get open, am i correct ?

Comment: dead wrong - each item in the carousel is currently displaying a toast - I need to modify this current behavior to start an intent

  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
         CarouselDataItem docu =  (CarouselDataItem) m_carouselAdapter.getItem((int) arg3);
         if (docu!=null)
             Toast.makeText(this, "You've clicked on:"+docu.getDocText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try something like-

```
    textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int index, long id) {
        String name = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
        Intent intent = null;

        if (name .equals("John F. Kennedy"))
            intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, KennedyActivity.class);
        if (name .equals("Lyndon B. Johnson"))
            intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, JohnsonActivity.class);
        if (name .equals("Richard Nixon"))
            intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, NixonActivity.class);
        if (name .equals("Gerald Ford"))
            intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, FordActivity.class);
        if (president.equals("Jimmy Carter"))
            intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, CarterActivity.class);
        if (name .equals("Ronald Reagan"))
            intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, ReaganActivity.class);
        if (name .equals("George H. W. Bush"))
            intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, SrBushActivity.class);
        if (name .equals("Bill Clinton"))
            intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, ClintonActivity.class);   
        if (intent != null) {
            intent.putExtra("KEY", name );
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```